# How to apply filter on pivot table in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have three models with the following relations

**MODEL-1: RecoringSchedule**

```
protected $recording_schedule = 'recording_schedules';

// relationship with processes
public function processes()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('Process', 'recording_uploads', 'recording_schedule_id', 'process_id');
}
```

**MODEL-2: Process**

```
protected $table = 'processes';
// relationship with recordings
public function recordings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('RecordingSchedule', 'recording_uploads');
}
```

**MODEL-3: RecordingUpload**

```
protected $table = 'recording_uploads';
```

Here model3 is the pivot table which contains **id, recording_schedule_id, process_id, created_at, updated_at**

I have a query,

```
$recordings = RecordingSchedule::with('processes')->orderBy('recording_date_time', 'desc')->paginate(50)->toArray()
```

The above query is return all the recordings with process.
Now how can I apply filter by process_id which is in pivot table?
like where process_id = 3

I have tried Kousha answer

It is displaying

```
[id] => 35
        [dialin_number] => 9908154124
        [operator_extension] => 121
        [recording_id] => 08631a03109
        [max_duration] => 10
        [recording_date_time] => 2014-07-31 13:06:00
        [status] => ADDED
        [created_by] => 32
        [created_at] => 2014-07-31 12:06:48
        [updated_at] => 2014-07-31 12:14:04
        [processes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => basic
                        [created_at] => 2014-07-10 12:22:06
                        [updated_at] => 2014-07-16 14:06:35
                        [pivot] => Array
                            (
                                [recording_schedule_id] => 35
                                [process_id] => 3
                            )

                    )

            )
```

and also other recordings as below

```
[id] => 39
        [dialin_number] => 939938333
        [operator_extension] => 141
        [recording_id] => 123456#
        [max_duration] => 30
        [recording_date_time] => 2014-07-31 12:19:00
        [status] => ADDED
        [created_by] => 32
        [created_at] => 2014-07-31 13:20:16
        [updated_at] => 2014-07-31 13:20:34
        [processes] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

In the second array recording with empty processes are displaying. Actually that recording belongs to process id 6. I don't want other recordings with other process id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to filter related models, or the main `RecordingSchedule` that have related with `id=3`?

Comment: No I want to apply on either on pivot table process_id or on process model id

Comment: Check Kousha's answer, but prefix column with table and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You don't apply the filter on the pivot, but on the table `processes`:

```
$process_id = 3;

$recordings = RecodingsSchedule::with([
    'processes' => function($query) use ($process_id)
    {
        $query->whereId($process_id);
    }
])->orderBy('recording_date_time', 'desc')->paginate(50)->toArray();
```

Comment: Good, however you need to prefix that field, otherwise `id` will be ambiguous.

Comment: production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '$process_id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '('' in C:\wamp\www\asr\ASR-25\app\controllers\RecordingScheduleController.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []

Comment: Also if I keep directly 3 instead of $process_id its working. But it is getting recordings with process id 3 and other recodrings also.

Comment: @ram, sorry I forgot the brackets around `$process_id`

Comment: @kousha but  I am getting recordings of other process id also. Please check my edited question..

Comment: @Kousha Yes Iam sure the relation is correct. Can you please update the answer